# Volume Control is not showing on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, volume

Volume Control is not showing such that slider .
I search many answer on Stackoverflow regarding this but No code is working well.

Most of the Answers I see there is a slider which control volume and added to subview I also try this but no slider.

```
     - (void)play
    {

    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.url];
     player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [player prepareToPlay];

    player.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    player.view.frame = self.view.frame;



    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    player.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:player];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                               object:player];




      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];


    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {  


         [[player view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320)];




    }
    else
    {

         [[player view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
    }





   // [[player view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
   // [[player view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
    [[player view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0];


     [self.view addSubview: player.view];

  // [ self.view addSubview: systemVolumeSlider];

    [player play];


    }
```

Comment: The movie player controller only shows the volume in fullscreen mode. Is it not showing it there?

Comment: got it. It is showing Sorry My Mistake.